# How to read asf header in C#?

Tags: .net, media, drm, asf

Having a wma file, how can one parse the header using c#?

The purpose is to find the Key ID in the Content Encryption Object (that forms a part of the DRM license). Do you use the WM Format SDK or WM rights manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a WindowsMediaPlayer class in the framework. It can open asf files and read particular header flags (like prebuffer time), that other libraries (taglib) do not read.

Comment: Can you link to the class? I can find a [`System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635239.aspx) class but that doesn't seem to be what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

WMA files are in the ASF format. You can download the [ASF specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=31334) from microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

There are sample code included in the [Microsoft Media Format 11 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757738%28VS.85%29.aspx) that display how to read headers from the ASF file format .

Good Luck!